# Google Visualization Meteor Implementation

Tags: mongodb, meteor, multidimensional-array

help me in upper or lower code problem must be appreciated
i want to make a bar chart and populate it from my collection from meteor i
want to  print exercises with there status 
but when i return one record from db it is working well graph is coming but
when coming two records its not working kindly help in it

```
Just help me that how i can make a correct JSON format for "google visualization graph" from meteor mongodb  

 function drawChart() {

  var status=Session.get('status');
  var graphData=Session.get("graphId");
  console.log("graphData==========",graphData)
  patientLog.find({patientId: graphData},{fields:    
  {patientExerciseName:1,status:1,_id:0}}).forEach(function      (myDoc) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  data.addRows([
  [ myDoc.status,          myDoc.patientExerciseName]
  ])
 var options = {
      chart: {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
```

})
}

Note : Foreach function when return two rows from database it not works

as i also try this

when i give JSON to my graph it is giving error "Invalid data table format:
 must have at least 2 columns".
 how i can make a JSON format which support Google visualization charts 
 please help me mine code is there

```
  function drawChart() {
  var status=Session.get('status');
  var graphData=Session.get("graphId");
  patientLog.find({patientId: graphData},{fields: 
  {patientExerciseName:1,status:1,_id:0}}).forEach(function (myDoc) {
  var Mydoc=JSON.stringify(myDoc)
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(Mydoc)
   var options = {
  chart: {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
  },
  bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
};
 var chart = new
  google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

chart.draw(data, options);
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that the data is received: in Meteor it is sometimes tricky as publications may not be ready when you draw your chart. You need to make sure you wait for the publication to be ready. (Use console log to log the data and see if it's there, as within the debugger the data will be there by the time you look it up

2) once you are sure the data is there, read the GoogleChart docs: it is a fairly extensive library with lots of examples, so just make sure you data matches the right format.

this question and answer should help:
[Building array and formatting JSON for Google Charting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245478/building-array-and-formatting-json-for-google-charting-api)