# Unable to print multidimensional array using foreach for google chart json

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-visualization

I am trying to create google line chart using json. As per this page [Building array and formatting JSON for Google Charting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245478/building-array-and-formatting-json-for-google-charting-api) the rows must be like

```
$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array('v'=>'20-01-13'), array('v'=>22)) );
```

for json encode.
My current code is

```
$connectDb=@dbconnect::getSettings();
$query=$connectDb->prepare("SELECT timestamp, tottrdqty FROM {$database} WHERE symbol IN(?,?) AND series=? AND timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY timestamp AND symbol");
$query->bind_param('sssss',$code,$code2,$series,$firstDate,$lastDate);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->get_result();
$query->close();
$connectDb->close();

while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $array[$row['timestamp']][] = $row['tottrdqty'];

}

/*foreach ($array as $date => $records)
{ echo $date . '<br />';
        foreach ($records as $record)
                { echo $record . '<br />'; }

}*/

$json_array=[];
$json_array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'date');
$json_array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');
$json_array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');
foreach ($array as $date => $records)
{


    $json_array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array('v'=>"$date"),
foreach ($records as $record){
array('v'=>"$record"),
}       
        ));
    }

print json_encode($json_array);`
```

If I remove second foreach everything works fine howwver I'm not getting the number in array. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try saving the row array, before adding to `'rows'`, e.g.

```
$json_array=[];
$json_array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'date');
$json_array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');
$json_array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'number');
$json_array['rows'] = array();
foreach ($array as $date => $records) {
  $row_array = array(array('v'=>"$date"));
  foreach ($records as $record) {
    $row_array[] = array('v'=>$record);
  }
  $json_array['rows'][] = array('c' => $row_array);
}

print json_encode($json_array);
```

also, to make it easy on google, recommend not wrapping rows values in quotes, e.g.

`array('v'=>$record)`

vs.

`array('v'=>"$record")`

Comment: it works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Had a semicolon missing added it.